# How to clean up strings with regex from list

Tags: python, regex

In every kind of file name that could be in the form of :

- String1_Todelete_restofstring.txt
- String2_Alsotoremove_restofstring.txt
- String3_2013_restofstring.txt
- String4_2011_restofstring.txt
- String5_restofstring_tosuppress.txt

I'd like to define a function with a *re.sub* to remove all keywords defined in a list, (or dictionary whatever) that woud include :

> "Todelete", 2013,2011, "Alsotoremove","tosuppress"

that way the example above (that could include different dates ) would became :

- String1_restofstring.txt
- String2_restofstring.txt
- String3_restofstring.txt
- String4_restofstring.txt
- String5_restofstring.txt

Please advise

___Edit _

Thanks for helpfull answers. I've found the Cobabunga implementation compact to implement in a function. In regard to questions in comments, no hold up in there as my intention was to keep the question as generic as possible to allow all kind of solutions, even thought about the date I think it can be implemented in a regex as well.

Comment: It sounds like a fine plan to me. What's the holdup? Have you run into any problems?

Comment: @Mouha What regular expression have you tried ?

Comment: If you're removing exact string matches you could just use `string.replace()`.  It'd probably be faster.

Comment: That depends in the size of your keywords dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will probably be more efficient then scanning each string as many times as you have keywords.

```
import re

strings = """String1_Todelete_restofstring.txt
String2_Alsotoremove_restofstring.txt
String3_2013_restofstring.txt
String4_2011_restofstring.txt
String5_restofstring_tosuppress.txt""".split()

keywords = set(("Todelete", "2013","2011", "Alsotoremove","tosuppress"))

for s in strings:
    print re.sub("_[^_.]+", lambda m: "" if m.group(0)[1:] in keywords else m.group(0), s)
```

Comment: When tested this method took about twice as long as iterating through the `keywords` and performing a `string.replace()` with each (e.g. the `rep` method in drewk's answer). It was though more than twice as fast as using `re.sub` similarly. (The `print` in the above was obviously not included.)

Comment: I suppose the list of strings and keywords in the original question is just an example. Try your timing with 1000 keywords and see how well each solution scales.

Answer (score 3):

You could build a regular expression that includes all the words you want to remove like this:

```
import re

to_remove = ["Todelete", "2013", "2011", "Alsotoremove", "tosuppress"]
pattern = "|".join("_?" + re.escape(x) for x in to_remove)

names = ["String1_Todelete_restofstring.txt",
         "String2_Alsotoremove_restofstring.txt",
         "String3_2013_restofstring.txt",
         "String4_2011_restofstring.txt",
         "String5_restofstring_tosuppress.txt"]

names_replaced = [re.sub(pattern, "", x) for x in names]
print names_replaced
```

Note that I've included an optional underscore ('_') before each of the replaced words because if you'd only replace `Todelete` in the first example, you'd end up with `String1__restofstring.txt` instead of `String1_restofstring.txt`.

The `re.escape` wouldn't be necessary for your specific example, but if your words contained any characters that have a special meaning in regular expressions, you'd get unexpected results without it.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
import re

st='''\
String1_Todelete_restofstring.txt
String2_Alsotoremove_restofstring.txt
String3_2013_restofstring.txt
String4_2011_restofstring.txt
String5_restofstring_tosuppress.txt'''

deletions=["Todelete", '2013','2011', "Alsotoremove","tosuppress"]

for line in st.splitlines():
    for deletion in deletions:
        if re.search('_'+deletion,line):
            line=re.sub('_'+deletion,'',line)
    print line
```

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments, the `re.search` is redundant.

Also, in the particular case, str.replace is *way* faster:

```
import re
import timeit 

st='''\
String1_Todelete_restofstring.txt
String2_Alsotoremove_restofstring.txt
String3_2013_restofstring.txt
String4_2011_restofstring.txt
String5_restofstring_tosuppress.txt'''

deletions=["Todelete", '2013','2011', "Alsotoremove","tosuppress"]


def rep():
    for line in st.splitlines():
        for deletion in deletions:
            line=line.replace('_'+deletion,'')


def reg():
    for line in st.splitlines():
        for deletion in deletions:
            line=re.sub('_'+deletion,'',line)            


print timeit.timeit('reg()', setup='from __main__ import reg', number=10000)     
print timeit.timeit('rep()', setup='from __main__ import rep', number=10000)
```

On my machine, `str.replace()` is about 5x faster.

Comment: The `search` is redundant isn't it?

Comment: I suppose, but it also makes the intent more clear. If you time it -- it is actually faster with the `re.search`.  Try it...

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea (not long, as I'm on my phone);

```
/(.*?)_.*?_(.*?)\.(\w{2,})/

group(1) + '_' + group(2) + '.' + group(3)
```